# mvc 4 How to call javascript function after @Html.RadioButtonFor clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

View Has :

```
<div Monthly @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DDPaymentOption, "Monthly", true) 
     Yearly  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DDPaymentOption, "Yearly", true)  
</div>
```

tried

```
$(":radio").click(function () {

    var Selectedvalue = $(this).val();
    var isDiv = document.getElementById('instalmentScheduleDiv');

    if (Selectedvalue == "Yearly")
    {
        isDiv.className =  "HideDiv";
    }
});
```

Does not hit the function

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle solution http://jsfiddle.net/Tv8EY/ now look in your browser, how does your html look? compare to this example and fix what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
$('#DDPaymentOption').click(function(){  
         if($(this).val()=='Yearly') 
         {
             $('#instalmentScheduleDiv').addClass('HideDiv');
         }
 });
```

And if you are using HideDiv Class to hide the div you can jquery methods to show or hide your  div element like

```
$('#instalmentScheduleDiv').hide(); // to hide the element
```

and/or

```
    $('#instalmentScheduleDiv').show(); // to show the element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
    var Selectedvalue = $(this).val();
    var isDiv = $("#instalmentScheduleDiv");
    if (Selectedvalue == "Yearly")
    {
        isDiv.hide();
    } else {
       isDiv.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All credit goes to: codingbiz

This is how you can do this.

```
function updatePostID(val)
{
    document.getElementById('PostID').value = val;

    //and probably call document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Then have a hidden field or other control for the PostID

```
@Html.Hidden("PostID", Model.addcomment.PostID)
//OR
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.addcomment.PostID)
```

[How do I update a model value in JavaScript in a Razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174465/how-do-i-update-a-model-value-in-javascript-in-a-razor-view)