# Updating Model with JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razorengine

I have a strongly typed model to my view. In my view I also have a foreach loop that itirates thru the content and renders an accordion with conent. i also have a search box that has a keyup event that fires when you type in it. The event fetches new data with a ajax call. All of this works fine. Now to the problem. Is there a way of updating the Model with JavaScript/Jquery with the new values from the ajax call. This is ASP.NET MVC 5 I am working in.
This is my code.

> View

```
@model List<CMP_FastaSamarbeten_ProjektWeb.Models.SubSiteViewModel>

        @{
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="accordion">
                <a href="#">
                    <h4>@item.Title</h4>
                    <h4 class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</h4>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-desc">
                <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
                <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
                <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
                <p>
                @item.Description
                <p>
                <div class="link">
                    <a href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }

<script>
    window.globalModel = [];
</script>
```

> ajax call and keyup event

```
    $("#searcheBar").on("keyup", function () {

    var input = this.value;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/SendSearchInput',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {input: input},
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.statusMessage);
        },
        success: function (data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i]["Title"]);
            }
            window.globalModel = data;
        }

    });//Ajax call


});//OnKey up
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Mvc?

Comment: Sorry. forgot. Yes. will add it

Comment: How would you suggest building a Live search bar with the Model approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a model value in JavaScript in a Razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174465/how-do-i-update-a-model-value-in-javascript-in-a-razor-view)

Comment: Found that post before posting my own. Couldn't find a way to implement any of the answers to my code.

Comment: once the page is rendered the model is gone, that's just a C# idiom which makes it simpler to generate HTML based on your data. When the page is rendered, all you have available is the resulting generated HTML. Your javascript can alter the HTML as much as it likes. So if your HTML is marked up sufficiently with classes/attributes/ids as needed, you can modify any part of the page that you need to based on the results of your ajax call.

Comment: So abandoning the model and send the list to the client with Ajax would be a better call?  I am thinking it would be hard to render the initial list if the user emptys the search box.  If I have manipulate the dom after the model has been loaded.

Comment: you can do both. Load the initial page with razor and then use ajax thereafter to manipulate subsequent requests. Or you could look into using a Partial View. The result of the ajax could be this partial view HTML content, instead of JSON. The model of the partial view would be the search results. Then you can use it in the initial page load (displays all items), and in subsequent ajax calls (just replace the contents of your results div with the result of the ajax call)

Comment: Hhm. Sounds interesting. Any idea on docs I could follow?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial would seem the obvious place to start. Plenty of tutorials around as well if you google partial view, or partial view ajax. I haven't followed any of them myself so can't comment on the quality of any individual one, but I'm sure most of them will give you the general idea at the very least.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. i went i another dierction